# Why do we not mention Aseres Yemei Teshuvah while bentching?

Tags: bentching, aseres-yemei-teshuva

During the Birchas Hamazon after eating bread, we do not make any mention of Aseres Yemei Teshuvah. Yet, in the shemoneh esrei we do.  Why do we not make mention of Aseres Yemei Teshuvah in the Birchas Hamazon?

Comment: Who is "we"? Some people do.

Comment: Hey B Weill, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thank you for your interesting question....hope you don't mind that I edited it to make it a little clearer. If I did anything you don't like you can fix it [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/46144/edit).

Comment: There is a minhag to say the Harachaman for Rosh HaShanah all throughout the Aseres Yemei Teshuvah.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75238/759

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Yitzchak Weiss (in Siaḥ Yitsḥaq 276) cites a few answers to this question:

> והנה בתשובת תודת שלמים למהר"י באסאן ז"ל [בלחמי תודה] בסי' כ"ד, נשאל, מדוע לא תיקנו רז"ל להזכיר איזה הזכרה שימי הדין הם בברהמ"ז כמו בתפלת י"ח, וכתב שם משום דברכת המזון כולה ברכת הודאה, והזכרת ימי תשובה אינם אלא לשבר את הלב, ועל כן אין לה מקום בברכהמ"ז. ועוד בזוה"ק פרשת תרומה [דף קנ"ג ע"ב], העלה דבברכהמ"ז אצטריך חדוה, וכיון דבעינן חדוה במקום גילה כזו לא תהא רעדה להזכיר ימי הדין דא"כ הו"ל תרתי דסתרן אהדדי, עכ"ד. ובס' זכר דוד להג' ר' דוד זכות [ליוורנו תקצ"ז] דף רכ"א כתב בזה, דמטעם המלך וזקניו היה מצוה להתענות בעשרת הימים, מהאי טעמא לא תיקנו הזכרה ולא באמירת הרחמן להזכיר מהדין, להורות דבימים הללו האכילה לא טובה היא, ואף שלא נוכל להתענות, ראוי שתהא אכילתנו ארעי ולא סעודת קבע, יעוש"ה עכ"ד. והנה עפ"י תירוץ הזכר דוד אם כתורה עושים כשאוכלים בר"ה, היה לרז"ל לתקן להזכיר בר"ה בברכהמ"ז מענין הדין, ומדלא תיקנו, יש להביא ראיה שגם בהם טוב יותר להתענות. ואין להשיב דלעולם רשאים לאכול בימי ר"ה, ורק משום לא פלוג מימים שבינתיים נמנעה ההזכרה, זה אינו, דגם תפלת וכן תן פחדך אין אומרים רק בר"ה, ולא בימים שבין כסה לעשור.

- **(in the name of Rabbi Yeshaya Bassan)** The reason we mention the Days of Repentence is to induce penitence.  *Birkat hammazon* is entirely thanksgiving, and contrition is inappropriate in this context.
- **(in the name of the Zohar)** *Birkat hammazon* requires joy from us, and the quaking before God that the Days of Repentance represent is incompatible with this joy.
- **(in the name of Rabbi David Zechut)** In truth, we should be fasting the entire 10 days, and not just on Yom Kippur.  Of course, we are unable to do such a thing, but in recognition of what *should* be, we do not mention the Days of Repentence after our meal. This shows our recognition that our eating and drinking is inappropriate, and not something we want to spend time on.