# Why does Sukkot have an individualized Harachaman insert in Bentching, but not Pesach or Shavuot?

Tags: bentching, chagim-holidays

We have הרחמן הוא יקים לנו את סוכת דוד הנופלת for Sukkot. But for Pesach and Shavuot, there's one generic הרחמן הוא ינחילנו את יום שכולו טוב. Why?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeia! Excellent question. Might I recommend that you [sign up](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup?ssrc=hero&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fjudaism.stackexchange.com%2f) so that you can save your questions and answers more easily?

Comment: [This article](https://www.ou.org/life/torah/brander_sukkos_5768_sukkah_life/) gives one explanation of why we say a harachaman on Sukkos, but no explanation of why we don't say one for the other Regalim.

Comment: On pesach there is a special harachaman.

Comment: Because no one composed a nice one? Why must every occasion have the same number of these?

Comment: @Mennyg, only on the first (two) night(s) afaik, Do some customs have a special one for the whole _Pesach_?

Comment: @msh210 yes. I know belz says it the entire Yom Tov.

Answer (score 1):

Some in fact do say to add a special harachaman for Pesach. It goes like this:

הרחמן הוא ינחילנו ליום שכולו טוב ליום שכולו ארוך ליום שצדיקים יושבים ועטרותיהם בראשיהם ונהנים מזיו השכינה ויהיה חלקנו עמהם

This is mentioned and discussed in an article found here:

http://shaalvim.co.il/torah/maayan-article.asp?backto=&ed=%E2%EC%E9%E5%EF%20%FA%F9%F8%E9%20%FA%F9%F2%E2%20&id=669

Though, the article does not bring up any additions for Shavuot nor does it mention why there are none.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Aryeh!

Comment: Note that this is in the hagada and replaces the regular הרחמן for Yom Tov and only for the seder, while סוכת adds the extra הרחמן and is used at all times. Your answer should explain this.

Comment: @sabba actually there are various customs of when to include this one and the one you reference about sukkot. See the article for details. Your custom isn't the only one or the official one.